# Traking uninstall action in Flutter(Android and IOS)

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, flutter

Have any method to track uninstall action from app? Android or IOS?

I like to get uninstall action and send some post http request to my backend, to delete the push notification token for exemple.

I believe I'll write Kotlin/Java and Swift code, but it's ok, but I can't find any soluction in internet.

Comment: for iOS you need a APNs (Apple Push Notification service), this way says you that the token is invalid, so, it mean that the device already hasn't the app

Comment: See: https://clevertap.com/blog/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/

Comment: I've already readed this article, but I thought android and IOS have nativilly ways to do this..

Comment: @LuizPalte were you able to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Is it still not supported?